# solution differential equation $8$ order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the general solution of the homogeneous differential equation whose characteristic equation is:

$$(r+5)(r-2)^3(r^2+1)^2=0$$

I know you think the first $4$ solutions: 
$-5,~2,~i$ and $-i$.

But being an $8$th equation, I don't know how to find the other solutions.
Can they help me?
 Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. You have to consider the multiplicity. There are no more roots.

Comment: Notice that $2, \pm \iota$ are repeated roots of the characteristic equation. In particular, $2$ is repeated thrice, $\pm \iota$ are repeated twice. Hence, the general solution would be $y = C_1 e^{-5x} + \left( C_2 + C_3 x + C_4 x^2 \right) e^{2x} + \left( C_5 + C_6 x \right) \cos x + \left( C_7 + C_8 x \right) \sin x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the roots of the auxiliary equation $~(r+5)(r-2)^3(r^2+1)^2=0~$ are $~-5,~2,~2,~2,~i,~i,~-i,~-i$.

Here the general solution is

\begin{equation}
y=c_1~e^{-5x}+(c_2+c_3~x+c_4~x^2)e^{2x}+(c_5+c_6~x)e^{ix}+(c_7+c_8~x)e^{-ix}\\
\\
\implies y=c_1~e^{-5x}+(c_2+c_3~x+c_4~x^2)e^{2x}+(c_5+c_6~x)(\cos x +i~\sin x)+(c_7+c_8~x)(\cos x -i~\sin x)\\
\\
\implies y=c_1~e^{-5x}+(c_2+c_3~x+c_4~x^2)e^{2x}+(a+b~x)\cos x+(p+q~x)\sin x
\end{equation}

where $~a=c_5+c_7~$, $~b=c_6+c_8~$, $~p=i(c_5-c_7)~$and$~q=i(c_6-c_8)~$.

All $c_1,~c_2,~c_3,~c_4,~c_5,~c_6,~c_7,~c_8,~a,~b,~p,~q$ are constants.

---

- Let $~m_1,~m_2,\cdots,~m_n~$ be $n$ distinct roots of the auxiliary equation, then the general solution is

$$y=c_1~e^{m_1x}+c_2~e^{m_2x}+\cdots +c_n~e^{m_nx}$$

- If out of $n$ roots $r~~(r<n)$ roots are equal, then the general solution is

$$y=c_1~e^{m_1x}+c_2~e^{m_2x}+\cdots+(k_1+k_2~x+k_3~x^2+\cdots+k_{r}~x^{r-1})e^{m_rx}+\cdots +c_n~e^{m_nx}$$